# What SYSTEM stored procedures are available in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to script the changes to a SQL Server Compact Edition database running on windows mobile 6 and could really use:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename 'MyTable.SomeColumn', 'BrandNewName', 'COLUMN'
```

What other **system** stored procedures are available?

What are the differences to the non compact version?

**Edit:**
 There **ARE** system stored procedures in ce, sp_rename is an example although it only seems to work against tables not columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there are any stored procedures available in SqlCe. My solution has been to create a class that contains a SqlCeEngine and expose my own methods like RenameColumn, and do the work internally.

EDIT 1: Now, that's very interesting (the existence of sp_rename). Considering the documentation out there that states there are no stored procedures in SQL CE, I don't think it's really fair to downvote anyone for that assumption.

EDIT 2: I've come across [this link from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372.aspx#) that indicates at least one other proc: sp_show_statistics. I'm assuming you're using SQL CE 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Again, you can't define your own stored procedures which is what ctacke's article says but the database runs off system stored procs internally. Which is what my question is about.

Comment: That looks as close to a definitive list as I can get :) thanks

Comment: There are not actually procs - you call them that way but they are mapped internal functions that are just exposed that way.  There is no internal secret stored proc engine.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL CE doesn't support stored procedures](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevelasker/archive/2008/02/11/stored-procedures-and-sql-server-compact-the-great-debate.aspx), so there are none at all.

Comment: User stored procs no, system stored procedures yes.

Comment: Downvote away people.  But I seriously doubt that the SQLCE team would have actually implemented a full SP engine and then exposed only 2 procedures and no ability to add user procs.  I'm willing to bet that the two listed aren't SPs at all but instead are hard-coded into the query engine.

Comment: I'm having to script changes to a compact database deployed to more than 40 devices. I saw sp_rename was there so my question was to find other sprocs that might help the scripting. So I think your declaration of 'there are none' posting an article about user sprocs is what got you downvoted.

Comment: I was already aware that user sprocs are not available, but that wasn't the question. Article is appreciated though, so +1 from me.

Comment: These "system" sprocs don't exist.  They are actually C functions that just get mapped to a sql function for some situations. There is no internal sproc engine.

Comment: Which is exactly what I suspected.